# Syntax error, unrecognized expression for href

Tags: jquery

When I add below script and run. I am getting this:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ul li
>   a[href=#!id1]

I am not sure which double quote causing the issue.

HTML

```
<ul>
 <li class="slist selected" id="id1"><a href="#!id10">Test1/a></li>
 <li class="slist" id="id2"><a href="#!id20">Test2</a></li>
 <li class="slist" id="id3"><a href="#!id30">Test3/a></li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var id = "#!" + window.location.href.split("!")[1];
    if ($("ul li a[href=" + id + "]").length) {
        console.log("present");    
    } else {    
        console.log("absent")
    }
});
```

Comment: According to the W3 specs, the exclamation character is not valid for the id attribute.
http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You need to enclose special characters in quotes when using a attribute based selector.

```
if ($('ul li a[href="' + id + '"]').length) {
```

---

Your version of selector would result

```
if ($("ul li a[href=#!...]").length) {
```

The `#!` will throw unrecognized expression.

---

My version where the `""` escape the characters

```
if ($('ul li a[href="#!..."]').length) {
```

Comment: In my scenario, I was using   $(document).on("click", "a[href^=#]", function(e) { and I added only single quote a[href^='#']" and it's working. Thanks Shaunak. upvote form my side.

Answer (score 19):

I tried the solution provided by

```
https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2885
```

which worked for me. I search for `[href=#] in js and replace with [href*=\\#]`

```
a[href*=\\#]:not([href=\\#])
```

Comment: I searched for [href=# and wrapped everything between the equals and closing bracket in quotes.

"[href=#abc]" became "[href='#abc']"

Answer (score 4):

you may add the below code in functions.php

```js
function modify_jquery() {
if (!is_admin()) {
 wp_deregister_script('jquery');
 wp_register_script('jquery', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js');
 wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
}
add_action('init', 'modify_jquery');
```

Comment: This worked. It appears jquery below the above version had issues. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error, because I have added these line codes somewhere in  my codes;

```js
$("a[href^='#']").click(function(e {
    e.preventDefault();
    var position = $($(this).attr("href")).offset().top; // if you remove this line, then error won't come
});
```

Comment: Does this answer has anything to do with mention question?

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because I hadn't closed the square brackets, got no errors until recently since we updated jquery to 3.6.3. Either that or some bug was fixed in newer versions of chrome, exposing my bug.