# Unrecognized expression: a[href^=#]

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I am trying to make a trivial "scrollTo element" function.

Console shows me the error:
**Syntax error, unrecognized expression: a[href^=#]** for **a[href^=#]** code

According to the reply on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31197452/syntax-error-unrecognized-expression-for-href) I wrapped the hash symbol into double quotes, but now console shows **Unexpected token ILLEGAL** for that.

Please, explain what I am doing wrong and how to fix it.

Here's my code:

```js
$(document).on('click', 'a[href^=#]', function () {
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop:  $('section[data-target="'+this.hash.slice(1)+'"]').offset().top }, 1000 ); 
        return false;
    });
```

```css
menu {
  background-color: #1abc9c;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

menu ul li a {
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
}


section {
  height: 300px;
  padding: 60px 0 0 45px;
}

.one {
  background-color: #3498db;
}

.two {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
}

.three {
  background-color: #f39c12;
}

.four {
  background-color: #2c3e50;
}
```

```html
<menu>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#one">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#two">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#three">Three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#four">Four</a></li>
  </ul>
</menu>

<section class="one" data-target="one">Section One</section>
<section class="two" data-target="two">Section Two</section>
<section class="three" data-target="three">Section Three</section>
<section class="four" data-target="four">Section Four</section>
```

[and the same in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5badmm2u/)

Comment: How exactly are you wrapping it? Wrapping it works fine for me.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Since `#` is a **metacharacter** of jquery, you have to wrap it by using **quotes** or you have to escape it by using `\\`,

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#"]', function () {
```

or

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[href^=\\#]', function () {
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/5badmm2u/1/)

Comment: It seems I wrapped it in quotes somehow incorrect for the first time. Now it works!

Comment: It is not just meta character in jQuery, but **also in the generic JS `.querySelectorAll()`** ! :) and same fix works there too :)

Answer (score 2):

by me, with jquery 3.5.1

- `a[href*=#]` → return error
- `a[href*="#"]` → works OK

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that's not what the thread owner asked for. While `^` indicates that the attribute has to "start" with a specific string, `*` isn't resticted to the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change to

> a[href*=\\#]

this work for me :)