# Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /blog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm adding a blog section to an existing single-page site, but running into some trouble with jQuery. The new blog will be hosted in a new /blog directory, and therefore the new menu item is different from all the other `href="#"` tags in the otherwise single-page index.html:

```
                            <!-- Menu -->
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
            <li><a href="#portfolio">Works</a></li>
            <li><a href="/blog">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
```

I've tried a variety of different selectors to get everything working correctly, but nothing seems to work. I gave the blog `href` a unique id and tried selecting it using `#wp-blog`, I tried selecting it using `.menu li a[href^='/']` and even the full URL with `.menu li a[href='{url}']`, but I'm not seeing any results. Also, I tried swapping the double and single quotes, and that didn't work either. I believe the code started out with single quotes on the outside and doubles were used in the `href` tags, but it wasn't working either way. Here's the JS in context:

```
$(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

    $(".menu li a[href^='#'], .scroll-btn a[href^='#'], .menu li a[href='/blog']").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(document).off("scroll");

        $("a").each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass("active");
        });
```

Despite several hours of research and throwing nearly a full day away at this, my console is throwing this error every time I scroll:

```
jquery-3.2.1.min.js:formatted:572 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /blog
    at Function.ga.error (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:formatted:572)
    at ga.tokenize (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:formatted:896)
    at ga.select (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:formatted:1073)
    at Function.ga (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:formatted:311)
    at Function.a.find (jquery-migrate-1.4.1.min.js:5)
    at r.fn.init.find (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:formatted:1194)
    at r.fn.init.a.fn.find (jquery-migrate-1.4.1.min.js:5)
    at a.fn.init.r.fn.init (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:formatted:1215)
    at new a.fn.init (jquery-migrate-1.4.1.min.js:5)
    at r (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:formatted:33)
```

I've already checked out other questions on jQuery selectors: [Select <a> which href ends with some string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303956/select-a-which-href-ends-with-some-string)

and jquery syntax error questions concerning href selectors here: [Syntax error, unrecognized expression for href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31197452/syntax-error-unrecognized-expression-for-href)

and also here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2824

as well as issues with multiple selectors here: [Multiple selector chaining in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736811/multiple-selector-chaining-in-jquery)

Any advice is greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: could you use `".menu li a, .scroll-btn a[href^='#']"` instead? feels like something is trying to treat /blog like a regular expression.

Comment: What is the `onScroll` function?

Comment: [jQuery Selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/): "To use any of the meta-characters (such as `!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^``{|}~`) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \\. For example, an element with `id="foo.bar"`, can use the selector `$("#foo\\.bar")`"

Answer (score 0):

Try using `'.menu li a, .scroll-btn a[href^="#"]'` instead.

I think jQuery is trying to treat **/blog** as a regular expression. So this error occurs.

Answer (score -1):

This may be an escape problem with the selector try:

```
$(".menu li a[href^='#'], .scroll-btn a[href^='#'], .menu li a[href='\\/blog']").on("click", function(e) {
```

Shown working on this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/aLenr3fp/2/