# How to use (or is it possible) MutationObserver to monitor window.location.pathname change?

Tags: javascript

I wonder if it is possible to use MutationObserver to monitor change in window.location.pathname (or window.location.hash).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No - you cannot use MutationObservers

The new EcmaScript 7 (in preview, draft) is going to have `Object.observe` which will allow you to monitor any object. However, that is in **not going to work**: observing global objects is a security risk and I doubt that any browser will allow that ([Chromium issue 494574](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=494574)).

Also, as other pointed out, window.location is a system object (of type Location Object) so it is not covered by `Object.observe`.

You can test that with Chrome 43 which already supports Object.observe: [kangax.github.io/compat-table/es7/#Object.observe](http://:%20kangax.github.io/compat-table/es7/#Object.observe)

So the only solution is to watch changes using timeout mechanism or use `window.onpopstate` (if you need to monitor only hash).

Comment: Actually, you **can** observe global objects (other than window), including `location`, as a quick test would verify. What you cannot do is observe `location.hash` and most of the other properties or `location`, because they are not regular properties.

Comment: The reasons you are not able to observe window.location using Object.observe() is because window.location returns an object of type Location Object (which is special read-only interface) and not "Standard" Object.

Comment: Actually, I observed `location` and it worked fine for non-standard properties such as `foo`. It just doesn't work for the "magic" properties such as `hash`.

Comment: The ticket you mention refers to `window`, which is indeed not unobservable, not `window.location`.

Comment: Just for others reading this old answer: `Object.observe` has been [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36258502/why-has-object-observe-been-deprecated/36259138) and I am currently not sure if there is an alternative which covers this case.

Answer (score 8):

**Mutation observers** observe the DOM, not objects, and are not relevant here.

**Object observers** cannot observe `location.hash`, **not** because `location` is a system object or a security risk, but because `hash` is a synthetic property managed internally by the equivalent of getters and setters.

In your case, you don't need any of that. You can watch for hash changes using the **`popState` event**.

```
window.onpopstate=function() { console.log("foo"); };

location.hash = "bar";
"foo"
```

I don't know what your intent is in watching for changes in `location.pathname`. That will cause a page reload before your handler has a chance to do anything.

Answer (score 3):

window.location.path is not part of the DOM, so you can't use MutationObservers on it.

But you can perform 'dirty checking' :

```
function watchPathChanges () {
    var currentPath = window.location.pathname;
    setInterval({
        if(window.location.pathname !== currentPath) {
            currentPath = window.location.pathname;
            //do something when it has changed
        }
    }, 50);
}
```

With EcmaScript 7, watching for property changes is supported natively with `Object.observe()`:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/observe

Comment: So it will be possible to observer window.location using Object.observe(). Is that correct? And it seems like Chrome 43 already supports it: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es7/#Object.observe

Comment: Most nowadays browsers are using EcmaScript 5, ES6 is planned for this year and I don't know when will ES7 be available.

If you want your code to work on all nowadays browsers, dont use Object.observe()

Comment: I'm confused. If the pathname changes, won't the page be reloaded before the next check?

Comment: Not necessarily. If the pushState is handled by JavaScript, as you would fine in a single-page app, then the page won't be reloaded.