# Remove hyperlink when link is click

Tags: jquery, css

Default link: `localhost/sample-page/`

Target link: `localhost/sample-page/#bottom`

```
<a href="#bottom">
  <div class="arrow"></div>
</a>
<div class="container" id="bottom">
```

This link is in the same page, the scenario is that when a link is clicked it will go to `localhost/sample-page/` but it showing `localhost/sample-page/#bottom`

How do I remove `#bottom` when the `a` is clicked?

Comment: That's a bookmark link. If you remove the bookmark (ie. the `#bottom` part of the `href`) then clicking the link will do absolutely nothing, which then leads to the question, why do you feel that you need to do this?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan is right, you might be incorrectly using the <a> tags

Comment: Use JS script to scroll to `#bottom` and get rid of `<a>` then. Your current code it HTML-only approach

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keep URL unaffected when anchor link is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17012592/keep-url-unaffected-when-anchor-link-is-clicked)

Answer (score 0):

Add your original link in the href tag. Check this [URL](https://jsfiddle.net/shoesheill/w7j16mqp/1/) https://jsfiddle.net/shoesheill/w7j16mqp/1/

```
<a href="https://jsfiddle.net/shoesheill/w7j16mqp/1/">
 <div class="arrow">Button</div>
 </a>
 <div class="container" id="bottom">
```